# SpeedFan cannot find my fan

Tags: windows-7, sony-vaio, speedfan

My laptop (SONY VAIO VGN-CR390) is getting hot recently and the fan doesn't seem to work at high speed. I installed SpeedFan and it reads my CPU temperature @60C+ consistently. However, it cannot find my fan, the *FANS* list is empty, so there's no fan speed reading or control whatsoever. Any idea how I can check and control my fan speed?

Sorry, I forgot to mention, it runs Winwdows 7 32bit.

Comment: Are you limited to Windows or are Linux tools a possibility as well?

Comment: Use a vacuum-cleaner to suck out the dust from the vents (starting at 1min): http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FwmaszoRyHM

Comment: @Shi, How would a Linux fan-monitoring program help while they’re using Windows? They’re not asking about a program to *set and forget* something; the program has to *actively* monitor, report, and adjust the fan speed while they’re using their computer.

Comment: @C2940680, Thanks. Yes, I opened up my laptop and cleaned it before I posted my question. It's actually quite clean, not so dusty in there.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that brand-name systems tend to use proprietary hardware and specifications. Alfredo frequently updates SpeedFan to support as much hardware as is possible, but unfortunately, sometimes manufacturers just don’t provide him with the tech specs he needs.

You have a few options:

- See if the latest [beta version](http://www.almico.com/sfbetaprogram.php) to see if it includes support for your laptop yet
- Use the *Get Config* button in the *Clock* tab to see if someone else with the same laptop has [shared](http://www.almico.com/sfhandleconfig.php) their configuration. Alternately, you could try setting the monitoring chip and settings yourself, but be careful since it is *possible* to mess up the hardware
- Add your laptop’s details to the [existing bug-report](http://www.bugtrack.almico.com/view.php?id=1874) in the [bug tracker](http://www.bugtrack.almico.com/view_all_bug_page.php) and monitor it for progress updates
- Try adjusting the scanning/access methods using the [command-line parameters](http://www.almico.com/sfarticle.php?id=3) options. Sometimes the default scan methods return incorrect results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks. I checked the configs and there's none for my laptop. Actually there ain't any for any VAIO VGN-xxxx laptops.

Comment: Did you try the options like disabling ISA Bus scanning or ACPI scanning? Did you add your information to the bug report? VAIO’s are already known to not work, so having more information can help Alfredo to find a way to add support for it.

Answer (score 0):

I really had a bad experience with speedfan software. It has some sort of bugs in it, don't know about other peoples. 
As per my suggestion you should use CPUID hardware monitor since it gives the temp of Hdd, cpu and gpu with cpu fan speed.

Link to the site is 
http://www.cpuid.com/softwares/hwmonitor.html

[image]

Comment: Thanks. It seems like this software cannot change the fan speed. I need something to increase my fan speed and cool down my laptop.

Comment: @LWZ - If your computer is overheating your fans are likely already maxed out.  I would find the cause of the overheating problem and solve that problem.

Comment: @Ramhound, the fan is not maxed out, it's quiet, not making much noise, and I put my hand close there's not much air flow blowing out.

Comment: Hey @LWZ is this software able to detect your fan?

Answer (score 0):

My Sony vaio S series has its own selectable preset fan modes. Go to vaio control centre, and under Power management, Power options, select the following fan modes:

Balanced - the fan speed will match the CPU performance "Standard thermal control setting"

Performance - the fan speed will always be maximum as the description states "give priority to heat discharge"

Silent - the fan speed will be quiet, supposedly "processing capability of CPU limited" but in the library I hardly notice any drop assuming you aren't gaming or installing or auto updating.

I used to wipe out all vaio utilities cos I felt they were wasting space and processing, but on a formatting of the hard disk I played around and found the vaio control centre.

Further things I did before formatting and using vaio control centre to try to control fan speed:

- msconfig, disable unnecessary startup items and services
- set all updating services such as antivirus and windows to notify me of updates rather than install automatically
- clean the pc with a virus scanner (use multiple scanners but uninstall the prev one before installing the next in case of conflict)

Answer (score -1):

All you need is [hwinfo32](http://www.hwinfo.com/download.php).  It is freeware that provides comprehensive hardware information and performs system health monitoring, reporting and alerting.

After you download and install it:

- Go to `Sensors`.
- On the botton is an icon that looks like a fan.  Click on it.
- Select what speed you want.

I think this option is called manual mode.

Comment: Please read [How do I recommend software](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/5329/how-do-i-recommend-software-in-my-answers/5330#5330) for some tips as to how you should go about recommending software. At the very least you should provide more than just a link, for example some additional information about the software itself.